# No audio jack senses

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

I plug in headphones and it's not detected at all same with my speakers. I try to use USB headphones and they pop up in the sound options as Logitech headphones. I want to get the green headphone jack working - I'm on Ubuntu 14.10.

In alsamixer the headphone option cannot be changed with the arrow keys - please help.

Card: HD-Audio Generic

Chip: Realtek ALC662 rev1

Comment: What computer/sound card are you using?  It may or may not help.

Comment: Card: HD-Audio Generic                            
Chip: Realtek ALC662 rev1

Comment: OK cool, seems fairly standard

Comment: is there a way to bump this, i truly need help

Comment: You just did, though commenting with no actual info is not good here.  As for drawing more attention to a question, you have no reputation on this site yet but once you have a lot, you can offer bounties if you want to give questions more attention.  It consumes some of your rep eg 50 points.

Comment: Until then, just making sure you give as much info in your question as possible and using a descriptive title and tags is the best you can do to get some help.  I don't know enough about this question to help or else I would.

Answer (score 0):

It might correct sound card has not been selected.
You can select the sound card in the `F6` key in `alsamixer`.
(If you can use a GUI environment, `pavucontrol` is recommended.)

Comment: The right soundcard was selected, i dont know what else to do,it has nothing to do with the sound card, the green audio jack is the problem because it's not detectign what i plugin,yet when i plug in a usb headset it detects it instantly